# Formula results outputting the wrong numbers for range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My formula is not outputting the proper result.

Weights that are between 5 and 8 on column I should output as 10 on column J. However, if you look at 7.30 weight, it is outputting as 15. 6.68 shows as 15. 6.88 as 15 and etc. Some of them are correct but the other half is wrong.

[image]

Is there something wrong with the formula?

```
=INDEX({7,10,15,30,55,70,80,100,110},MATCH(1*I1,{0,4,8,15,25,35,45,55,65,70}))
```

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet with this exact dataset. There might be something wrong with the format of your number input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear I2:I and try this in I2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(I2:I="",,VLOOKUP(1*I2:I,{{0;4;8;15;25;35;45;55;65},{7;10;15;30;55;70;80;100;110}},2,TRUE)))`

In your original formula, for starters, you have 9 elements in one array and 10 in the other.

However, I find `VLOOKUP` easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

try in J2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I2:I, 
 {{0;  4;  8; 15; 25; 35; 45;  55;  65},
  {7; 10; 15; 30; 55; 70; 80; 100; 110}}, 2, 1)))
```